# NTLM authentication with Apache VFS

Tags: sharepoint-2013, webdav, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-commons-vfs

I am trying to use Apache VFS to read files inside SharePoint 2013 mounted as a network drive. I use the following code

```
        try {
        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
        manager.addProvider("http", new WebdavFileProvider());
        manager.setCacheStrategy(CacheStrategy.ON_CALL);
        manager.setFilesCache(new SoftRefFilesCache());
        FileObject fileObject = manager.resolveFile("http://sp2013w2k12r2/PuneetsLibrary/");
        System.out.println(fileObject.getFileSystem().hasCapability(Capability.LIST_CHILDREN));
        System.out.println(fileObject.isFolder());
    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i get the following error

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
>   INFO: ntlm authentication scheme selected
>   Aug 03, 2016 5:29:55 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processWWWAuthChallenge
>   INFO: No credentials available for NTLM @sp2013w2k12r2:80
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not determine the type of file "http://sp2013w2k12r2/PuneetsLibrary".
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:1526)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.isFolder(AbstractFileObject.java:1726)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DecoratedFileObject.isFolder(DecoratedFileObject.java:211)
>       at SharePointVFSMain.main(SharePointVFSMain.java:18)
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "Unauthorized".
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:88)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:41)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.execute(WebdavFileObject.java:594)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.getProperties(WebdavFileObject.java:632)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.getProperties(WebdavFileObject.java:620)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.getProperty(WebdavFileObject.java:664)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.getProperty(WebdavFileObject.java:671)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.isDirectory(WebdavFileObject.java:716)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.webdav.WebdavFileObject.doGetType(WebdavFileObject.java:405)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:1517)
>       ... 3 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what had to be done. The java process if run with credentials of the user who has permissions to SharePoint site, is able to read the documents.